# Objective C Property Syntax

Tags: objective-c

I have quick question regarding my code:

This is my Animal.h header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Animal : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic) int age;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *breed;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImage *image;


-(void) bark;

-(void)barkNumTimes: (int)numOfTimesToBark;

-(void)barknumTimes:(int)numberOfTimes loudly:(bool) isLoud;

-(int) ageInDogYears: (int)humanYears;

@end
```

For some reason at the line:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIImage *image;
```

I get an error saying that "Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of  object type".

My ViewController.m class is where I created three Animal objects and used the UIImage property which I created in Animal.h and set each of the Animal objects UIImage property to a certain image I have in my supporting files:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Animal.h"
#import "Puppy.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.whichDog = 0;

    Animal *whiteDog = [[Animal alloc]init];

    [whiteDog setName:@"white"];
    [whiteDog setBreed:@"White Dog"];
    whiteDog.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whitedog.jpeg"];

    Animal *brownDog = [[Animal alloc] init];
    [brownDog setName:@"brown"];
    [brownDog setBreed:@"Brown Dog"];
    brownDog.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"browndog.jpeg"];

    Animal *husky = [[Animal alloc] init];
    [husky setName:@"husky"];
    [husky setBreed:@"Husky Dog"];
    husky.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"husky.jpeg"];

    self.myAnimals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self.myAnimals addObject:whiteDog];
    [self.myAnimals addObject:brownDog];
    [self.myAnimals addObject:husky];

    Puppy *pup = [[Puppy alloc]init];
    [pup setName:@"coby"];
    [pup setBreed:@"Portuguese Water Dog"];
    pup.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puppy.jpeg"];
}

- (IBAction)newDogBarButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender{

    int numOfDogs = (int)[self.myAnimals count];
    int randomIndex = arc4random() % numOfDogs;

    Animal *randomAnimal = [self.myAnimals objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:1.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown animations:^{
        self.imageView.image = randomAnimal.image;
        self.carNAme.text = randomAnimal.name;
        self.extra.text = [randomAnimal breed];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
    sender.title = @"And Another";
    self.whichDog = randomIndex;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

For some reason in Animal.h I keep getting that error which says "Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of  object type". I am not very sure on what this retain or strong means in the properties, but can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong in my code. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Are you using ARC?  Why are you mixing `strong` and `retain` with your properties?

Comment: Hi, I am actually not sure what strong and retain means which is why I am confused on which one to use.

Comment: We used to use `retain` before ARC was introduced. We now use `strong` in ARC. So replace `retain` with `strong`.

Comment: @ClayHorder Were you using a guide or tutorial?  Because it's probably way outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIImage belongs to UIKit, so import UIKit instead of Foundation

Comment: So add another import statement like this on the top: #import "UIKit" ?

Comment: No, replace the `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` with `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` (or `@import UIKit;`).

Comment: replace Foundation with UIKit, UIKit includes the Foundation framework. You could probably use the syntax `@import UIKit;`

Comment: Alright. I got the code the work. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Oh so I it looks like I don't even need: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>.

Comment: Alright. Did it! Didn't know about that functionality before :)